# How to set up different MX records for outbound and inbound email?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I would like to use my own outbound email server `Haraka with Node.js` and Google Apps for inbound mail.

Now my [domain registrar](http://iwantmyname.com) gives one click Google Apps setup, however I've already set up my own outbound server and it says:

```
Caution: The main domain name (www.)mydomain.com is 
using MX : mail.mydomain.com already.  

If you want to add Google Apps, you need create a subdomain, 
e.g. xyz.mydomain.com or remove MX : mail.mydomain.com.
```

So how can I implement both correctly with `SPF` and `DKIM` records without any interference?

*P.S. I'm very new at this topic, sorry if my question feels a bit confusing*

Comment: This is not an "email" question but something specific to Google Apps and/or to your domain name registrar. I'd suggest you go check their respective customer support.

Comment: I recommend joining the Haraka IRC channel for asking questions about Haraka - it's #haraka on irc.freenode.org - we're very friendly on there and can answer generic email questions too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MX  records are not used for outbound mail,  only for inbound.  if your current mail. domain.com server is outbound only then delete your current MX  record.

Comment: Alright. And what about SPF and DKIM records?

Comment: @CIRK You set those up the way Google instructs you to.

Comment: SPF can use include your MX records as allowed hosts, but that's not the only way to do it. You could instead list the hosts explicitly or include your MX records AND your outgoing-only hosts. MX records have no impact on DKIM.